# How can use API to get all Publishing pages in the site collection using a specific Content Type?

Tags: content-type, publishing-site, publishing-page, spquery

I need to use API to return all Publishing pages using a specific content type in a publishing site. this includes querying all sites in the site collection. Can I do that with SPQuery?

I am using SharePoint 2010 / Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use SiteDataQuery as replied by Thomson above.
Here is some sample code

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

//Server template for page library is 850
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='850' Hidden='TRUE' />";  

query.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='URL' Nullable='True' Type='URL' /><FieldRef Name='Title' Nullable='TRUE' Type='Text' />";

query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive'  />";
query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType'/><Value Type='Text'>CT_Page_News</Value></Eq></Where>"

DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to Query the siteCollection you need to use SPSiteDataQuery